# Сколько байт памяти занимает переменная?

Tags: c, структуры

Сколько байт памяти занимает переменная, имеющая тип описанной следующим образом структуры:
struct AF{int Z[n]; int X[m]; char F;}
при n=19, m=12?

Comment: Так запустите и проверьте? Зачем спрашивать.

Answer (score 6):

Зависит от выравнивания.

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct AF1
{
    int Z[19]; 
    int X[12]; 
    char F;
};

#pragma pack(4)
struct AF8
{
    int Z[19]; 
    int X[12]; 
    char F;
};
```

А что получается — см. https://ideone.com/z4ISke